# Index/Match Array Not Returning Some Combinations Correctly

Tags: excel-formula

I am using an index/match formula as an array (provided by an awesome person on another forum) to return a specific result using 3 criteria, I just realized that a particular combination is not returning properly. The formula should return the cell that these three criteria intersect:

BM96 (LTV) LTV Data Range is AZ60:AZ69
BM97 (Coverage) Coverage Data Range is BA60:BA69
BM98 (Credit Score) Credit Score Range is BB59:BI59

Data Table to return value from is BB60:BI69. Here is the formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(BB60:BI69, MATCH(IF(BM96>95%, 97%, BM96)&BM97, AZ60:AZ69&BA60:BA69,-1), MATCH(IF(BM98>760, 760,BM98), BB59:BI59,-1)), INDEX(BB60:BI69, MATCH(IF(BM96>95%, 97%, BM96)&BM97, AZ60:AZ69&BA60:BA69, -1),MATCH(IF(BM98>760, 760, BM98), BB59:BI59,-1)))*100
```

(I am pressing Ctrl+Sht+Enter) when completing formula

When using the following combination of criteria, the result should be .96 but instead it returns .72 which is the correct column but 2 rows lower than it should be

LTV 92%
Coverage 30%
Credit Score 680

Here is the data:

```
    AZ  BA  BB  BC  BD  BE  BF  BG  BH  BI
 59 LTV Coverage    760 759 739 719 699 679 659 639
 60     97% 35% 0.58%   0.70%   0.87%   0.99%   1.21%   1.54%   1.65%   1.86%
 61     97% 25% 0.46%   0.58%   0.70%   0.79%   0.98%   1.23%   1.31%   1.50%
 62     97% 18% 0.39%   0.51%   0.61%   0.68%   0.85%   1.05%   1.17%   1.27%
 63     95% 30% 0.38%   0.53%   0.66%   0.78%   0.96%   1.28%   1.33%   1.42%
 64     95% 25% 0.34%   0.48%   0.59%   0.68%   0.87%   1.11%   1.19%   1.25%
 65     95% 16% 0.30%   0.40%   0.48%   0.58%   0.72%   0.95%   1.04%   1.13%
 66     90% 25% 0.28%   0.38%   0.46%   0.55%   0.65%   0.90%   0.91%   0.94%
 67     90% 12% 0.22%   0.27%   0.32%   0.39%   0.46%   0.62%   0.65%   0.73%
 68     85% 12% 0.19%   0.20%   0.23%   0.25%   0.28%   0.38%   0.40%   0.44%
 69     85% 6%  0.17%   0.19%   0.22%   0.24%   0.27%   0.37%   0.39%   0.42%
```

[image]

I have tried lot's of things but can't seem to make this work, I know the issue is related to the LTV but can't understand why it is returning the row for 16% rather than 30%.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this alternate non-CSE formula using the newer AGGREGATE function.

```
=INDEX(BB60:BI69, AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW(1:10)/((AZ60:AZ69>=MIN(AZ51, MAX(AZ60:AZ69)))*(BA60:BA69>=AZ52)), 1), IFERROR(MATCH(AZ53, BB59:BI59, -1), 1))
```

[image]

Comment: I've added error control for credit score > 760 and ltv > 97%. Do you really require error control on coverage as well?

Comment: I think I can get away with no error control on coverage

Comment: Yeah, you would need a maxif sort of arrangement for coverage based on ltv; while doable, it was a bit more complicated than I wanted to get into if unnecessary. I figured the available coverage came from a dependent drop down list based on ltv

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it did not work, it returned 1.27 for every combination. I ended up creating another small table of all possible LTVs with the correct LTV to round to and then using a Vlookup to choose the correct LTV value. So instead of referring to the LTV entered by the user I take that user entered LTV and find it on the table and use the corresponding value from the vlookup formula. I didn't want an additional table but there was no escaping it.
=VLOOKUP(BM96,BS83:BT101,2)

Comment: You're not adapting the formula properly for your real-life situation. Note that I left all addresses relative and subject to the configuration I demonstrated in my sample image. Without making some addresses absolute, you cannot fill right/fill down/copy that formula to additional locations.

Comment: Rookie mistake, after making the corrections it worked. I'll be honest I am not really understanding it completely.

I had another person from computing.net that provided this formula that also works:
=IFERROR(INDEX(BB60:BI69,MATCH(IF(BM96>95%,97%,IF(BM96>90%,95%,IF(BM96>85%,90%,85%)))&BM97,AZ60:AZ69&BA60:BA69,-1),MATCH(IF(BM98>760,760,BM98),BB59:BI59,-1))/100,INDEX(BB60:BI69,MATCH(IF(BM96>95%,97%,IF(BM96>90%,95%,IF(BM96>85%,90%,85%)))&BM97,AZ60:AZ69&BA60:BA69,-1),MATCH(IF(BM98>760,760,BM98),BB59:BI59,-1)))*100